# What experiments led to the sign of the electron's charge?

Tags: physics, philosophy-of-science, experimental-physics, electricity

The famous Millikan's oil drop experiment in 1908 determined the magnitude of charge of the electron to be 1.59*10^(-19) C. However, it was well known that electron has a negative charge. Although there is no definition of charge *per se*, the original experimental identification is still Franklin's experiment i.e., whenever glass is rubbed with silk, the glass becomes negatively charged. I am searching for those original experiments which showed that the charge on the electron behaved the  same way as glass rod rubbed with silk? Thanks

Comment: Sign of charge is determined in electrolysis experiments.

Comment: I am afraid this is not correct. Electrolysis had nothing to do with the sign of electron charge in the beginning. The sign of the electron must have been determined by electrostatic experiments.

Comment: In electrolysis, ions of one sign accumulate on one side, ions of other sign on another. Ion's sign is determined by whether it has an extra electron(s) or some deficient electron(s). Therefore, ANY experiment with electrolysis immediately gives you the sign of the electron charge.

Comment: Dear Alexandre, I am a chemist by training with a decade in this field. I can confirm that electrolytic experiment did not lead the determination of electron's sign. The early experiments must have been conducted by electrostatics by physicists. The sign on ion and the sign on the electron is like a chicken and egg paradox. How do we know the sign on the ion, because the sign on the electron is negative? You see it is a circular argument.

Comment: Electrostatic does not help because you cannot isolate electrons. I mean in the early experiments.

Comment: Early electroscopes were the only means to determine the sign of the charge on a object and they still are used today in demos. You don't need to isolate electrons. You would charge an object and compare its behavior with a charged glass rod. Fancier electroscopes included the quadrant electrometer in the 19th century.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something but in the early days people thought of [electricity as a fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_theory_of_electricity), and there was controversy as to whether there was a single fluid (Franklin) or two. Franklin, and many after him, thought of electric current as being, in fact, *positively* charged. But once the notion of electron got currency [Crookes showed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron#Discovery_of_free_electrons_outside_matter) that their charge must be negative by using deflection by cathode rays in 1870-s, for example.

Comment: @M. Farouq: This is the same vicious circle: when you charge an object to insert to your electroscope, how do you know, whether you add electrons or subtract them. It seems (from the Wikipedia article "Electron") that the charge sign was not known until electrons could be isolated (in electronic beams).

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, Let me ask an interesting question along your line of thinking. How did early 8th and 19th century physicists found that one terminal of the cell is negatively charged and one end is positively charged? It took me several years and discussions from a historian at Berkeley. It was not electrolysis. You are right when you say that electrons must have been isolated, most likely in the cathode ray tubes.

Comment: @ Conifold, I think we have to search early papers on cathode rays and their electrostatic deflection. The core idea makes sense, but I am looking for the exact apparatus which conclusively led to the sign of the charge on the electron.

Comment: @M. Farook: This seems to be correct. Until the experiments with cathode ray tubes they did not know what is the sign of electron charge. And the convention of signs was purely arbitrary.

Comment: Yes Alexandre, It is amazing that we still have no definition of the charge today. It is a property, one could have called it green and yellow. All we know that we have two types, one which behaves like a glass rod rubbed with silk and the other one with amber. This is still the "experimental" definition of positive and negative charge today. See Perrin's experiment below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we have an answer. The original paper is in French by Perrin. The translation is in Nature (1896). NEW EXPERIMENTS ON THE KATHODE RAYS Jean Perrin. It is a two paged article. https://www.nature.com/articles/053298a0

With the help of magnetic deflection, he directed the cathode rays into a electroscope connected to a Faraday cylinder (see Figure 1). It is a nice experiment. In the end he concludes "In short, the Faraday's cylinder became negatively charged when the kathode rays entered it, and only when they entered it; *the kathode rays are then charged with negative electricity* (emphasis is his own). He does not give the details of his electroscope. However, testing the sign of the electroscope was rather an elementary experiment with charged rods.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this goes back to the Hall effect.  The original experiment, carried by Hall in 1879, allows the [determination of carrier densities](https://www.nist.gov/pml/engineering-physics-division/popular-links/hall-effect/hall-effect-measurements-introduction).  The [original paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20110727010116/http://www.stenomuseet.dk/skoletj/elmag/kilde9.html) by Hall does not, however, mention this application so it is not clear how quickly carrier densities were determined using this method, although one would think this was done before Perrin did his own work approx 17 years later as referenced in another anwser.

Comment: Perrin does not cite Hall. In the 1870s, the centers of Physics were in Europe and probably his did not get immediate attention. Sadly, it is cited only 23 times.